# printing only half of the text from the pdf

Tags: php, pdftotext

I am printing all texts form pdf files but it seems to have only printing the text from first pdf only.Also for the first pdf it is only printing a small portion from it.I am doing it inside a loop ,Can any one say me what i am doing wrong

here is my code

```
$new_array = array_combine($files, $extensio);
foreach($new_array as $key => $value)
{
    if($value=="pdf")
    {
        echo $key;
        include_once('class.pdf2text.php');
        $a = new PDF2Text();
        $a->setFilename('flies/'.$key); 
        $a->decodePDF();
        echo $a->output();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried checking for errors ?

Comment: @SyedQarib It is not printing any errors, just echoing a few portion of the first pdf